# DB locale/collation on Heroku

Tags: heroku, collation

We're developing a swedish web site using hobo and rails. We want to host the site on Heroku but we're having a problem with the sort order of results from the DB. Does anyone know if there's a way to specify the collation for the underlying standard Heroku DB?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to know if there is a Heroku recommended way of going about this, but I solved a similar problem by merging in collation (and in my case encoding as well) in the initializer. Inside the Rails::Initializer.run block in environment.rb

```
class Rails::Configuration
 def database_configuration
   # Heroku overwrites the database.yml file   
   require 'erb'
   YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_configuration_file)).result).each_value {|env| env.merge!({"encoding" => "utf8", "collation" => "utf8_general_ci"}) }
 end
end
```

It probably worth mentioning this was done in Rails 2.3.5 so milage may vary.